# Actualizar Automáticamente Datagridview en vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Tengo un Datagridview donde le cargo una tabla de MYSQL, lo conecto con ODBC, y el problema es cuando voy agregar a una consulta a la tabla, porque no me lo actualiza automaticamente tengo que cerrar y abrir de nuevo para poder ver los datos agregados.

Esto es lo que hago para cargar el DataGrid

```
Public Function ObtenerCampeones() As List(Of Campeon)
    Dim resultado As New List(Of Campeon)
    Dim connection As ADODB.Connection = conectar()

    Dim recordSet As Recordset = connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM campeoness;")

    While (Not recordSet.EOF)
        Dim campeon As New Campeon

        campeon.id = DirectCast(recordSet.Fields("id").Value, Integer)
        campeon.Nombre = recordSet.Fields("nombre").Value.ToString()
        campeon.Fuerza = DirectCast(recordSet.Fields("fuerza").Value, Integer)
        campeon.Destreza = DirectCast(recordSet.Fields("destreza").Value, Integer)
        campeon.Inteligencia = DirectCast(recordSet.Fields("inteligencia").Value, Integer)
        campeon.Resistencia = DirectCast(recordSet.Fields("resistencia").Value, Integer)

        resultado.Add(campeon)

        recordSet.MoveNext()

    End While
    connection.Close()
    Return resultado

End Function



Private Sub CargarDataGrid()

        campeones = persistencia.ObtenerCampeones()

        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add()

        dataTable.Columns.Add("Nombre")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Fuerza")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Destreza")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Inteligencia")
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Resistencia")

        For Each campeon As Campeon In campeones
            dataTable.Rows.Add(campeon.Nombre, campeon.Fuerza, campeon.Destreza, campeon.Inteligencia, campeon.Resistencia)
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable
        DataGridView1.Refresh()


    End Sub
```

Los campeones son los jugadores que agrego a la tabla, se le puede agregar Nombre, fuerza, destreza, inteligencia y resistencia.

Comment: Después de cualquier operación (agregar, edita, eliminar) llama a esta función `ObtenerCampeones()` para que se carguen los datos.

Comment: Lo tengo pero igual no me lo actualiza

Answer (score 0):

¡Resuelto! añadí un Timer con un intervalo de 1000 (1000 = 1 seg), en el código del Timer llame a la función que actualiza la Base de Datos y abajo de eso puse Timer.Start
Y cuando inicia el formulario le supe Timer.Start también, cosa que esté en bucle todo el tiempo.